# ServiceStack: VS 2012 Add service reference

Tags: c#, soap, servicestack

I'm having issues adding a service reference to my soap endpoint. I even tried adding the address for the hello example on SS website, http://mono.servicestack.net/soap11, and couldn't generate the wsdl. All my dtos (on my project) are decorated with data contract/ member. I've also changed the assembly to point to the target namespace. I've tried adding it as a web reference and also marking the reuse type in reference assembly off, but still no luck. Is there anything im forgetting to do? Let me know if more information is required.

```
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WILP_API
{
    public class ApplicationHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public ApplicationHost() : base("GreetingService", typeof(GreetingService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}​
```

```html
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace WILP_API
{
    [Route("/hello/{Name}","GET")]
    [DataContract(Namespace="WILP_API")]
    public class GreetingRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```html
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace WILP_API
{
    [Route("/hello/{Name}", "GET")]
    [DataContract(Namespace="WILP_API")]
    public class GreetingResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}​
```

```html
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WILP_API
{
    public class GreetingService : IService
    {
        public GreetingResponse Any(GreetingRequest request)
        {
            GreetingResponse response = new GreetingResponse();
            response.Result = "Hello, " + request.Name + "!";
            return response;
        }
    }
}​
```

```html
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("WILP_API")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("WILP_API")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("133bdb3e-442d-45ad-9cc2-02fbcd50c8ac")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",
           ClrNamespace = "WILP_API")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types", ClrNamespace = "ServiceStack")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types", ClrNamespace = "ServiceStack.Client")]​
```

Errors:

> Error 5   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service
>   reference 'ServiceReference3'.  Please check other error and warning
>   messages for details.
>
> Warning   3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail:
>   There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is
>   dependent on. XPath to wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply']
>
> Warning   4   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There
>   was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent
>   on. XPath to wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:service[@name='SyncReply']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_ISyncReply']
>
> Warning   2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An
>   exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a
>   reference to a schema element with name 'GreetingRequest' and
>   namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types' could not be
>   resolved because the element definition could not be found in the
>   schema for targetNamespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types'.
>   Please check the XSD documents provided and try again. XPath to Error
>   Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://schemas.servicestack.net/types']/wsdl:portType[@name='ISyncReply']

Comment: Please delete this all `code snippet` parts since these are C# code and show your error and warning messages as a text instead of image.

Comment: I apologize. I hope this format is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that only a [single WSDL Namespace](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#single-wsdl-namespace) is used for all DTO's. As ServiceStack built-in DTO's are already defined with the `http://schemas.servicestack.net/types` it's easiest and recommend to just stick with that which you can do by adding an assembly `[ContractNamespace]` attribute in your `Assembly.cs`, e.g:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://schemas.servicestack.net/types",
           ClrNamespace = "WILP_API")]
```

Which will apply to all DTO's in that Assembly under the `WILP_API` namespace so they'll no longer need to have namespaces defined on the DTO's, e.g:

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}","GET")]
[DataContract]
public class Greeting : IReturn<GreetingResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class GreetingResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Also only the Request DTO uses the `[Route]` attribute. You should also follow the `Greeting/GreetingResponse` [Request/Response DTO Naming Convention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#dto-naming-conventions).

#### Changing the WSDL Namespace

Whilst it's recommended to stick with the default ServiceStack namespace if you must change it you would also need to configure the different namespace in your HostConfig, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://new.namespace.com",
});
```

### [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference)

Instead of using SOAP endpoints and WSDL you should instead consider using [ServiceStack's new Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference) which offers numerous [advantages over WCF's SOAP Add Service Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference#advantages-over-wcf).

Comment: Thank you. I literally read that section a million times, but must have thought ServiceStack was my namespace. I would upvote but I don't have enough rep. Anyway, this is the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this exactly very recently, and I'd like to specifically expand the above answer. It turned out in my case to have 100% to do with the naming convention used.

The naming convention recommended [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#dto-naming-conventions) is enforced to some degree when SS generates a wsdl. I'm not certain if it is intended or a bug, but ending a request DTO with 'Request' (at least as of Jan 2017) causes those three warnings and a failure when adding a standard .Net service reference in VS.